# Access Denied on form submit()

Tags: jquery, forms, internet-explorer

Im using jquery form plugin (http://jquery.malsup.com/form) and on IE 8 and 9 its not working. IE denies access to `form.submit();` Example on author page is ok, my not. Do I need additional configuration for IE?

```
$(parent + ' form').ajaxForm({
    success: function(data) {
        $("#cont").html(data);
    },
    beforeSubmit: function(arr, f, o) {
        o.dataType = "html";
    },
    iframeSrc: urlTab['upload']
});
```

It's not a server issue, request it not made. No cross domain and other common problems.

Comment: Form action is not hosted on your server? Then it is a same origin issue

Comment: everything is on same server, same domain etc.

Comment: yes, everywhere is standard (80).

Comment: Whats the parent in your case?

Comment: additionally you don't need to specify dataType beforeSubmit. You can specify dataType outside function also

Comment: Are you trying to use fileUploads using jquery form plugin? or Simple Form Posting. Simple form posting don't need iframeSrc. This option will only be useful if you are using file upload using jquery form. In fileupload case use `iframe : true` also

Comment: yup, im trying to upload a file. Adding `iframe: true` didnt help

Comment: possible duplicate of [form submit - IE access denied - same domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667856/form-submit-ie-access-denied-same-domain)

Answer (score 1):

Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KvXK4/1/). Simple form submission. It works in IE 7, 8 and 9. Flow goes to error function because test.html does not exist on jsFiddle. But No access denies error occurred on IE.

I am using `form.submit();` it works fine.

I got your problem

Here is a link which resolves your problem [“Access is denied” JavaScript error when trying to access the document object of a programmatically-created  (IE-only)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886547/access-is-denied-javascript-error-when-trying-to-access-the-document-object-of)

You can see your logs of forms plugin by adding this code.

```
$.fn.ajaxSubmit.debug = true;
```

Here is Full COde

```
$.fn.ajaxSubmit.debug = true;

$(document).ajaxError(function(ev,xhr,o,err) {
    alert(err);
    if (window.console && window.console.log) console.log(err);
});

$('form').ajaxForm({
    dataType:'html',
    iframe:true,
    iframeSrc : "javascript:'<html><body><p>Hello<\/p><script>do things;<\/script>'",
    success: function(data) {

    },
    beforeSubmit: function(arr, f, o) {

    },
    error: function(responseText){
        alert(responseText.status+'  ::  '+responseText.statusText);
    }
});
$('#submitBtn').click(function(){
    $('form').submit();
});
```

Comment: that example works to me too, but the code in question which is a part of bigger project still not and i dont have any idea why.

Comment: @WombaT see my edited answer. This will works fine for your case

Comment: setting iframeSrc didnt change anything, still cant send form.

Comment: solved: form was loaded by ajax and IE was blocking it. After changing view and a controller to load form with whole page i can use ajaxForm without problems on IE.

Comment: Good the hear that. Cheers :)