# IE 8-9 SCRIPT5: Zugriff verweigert (Access Denied) on Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-forms-plugin

i have an iframe in my page from another sub domain.
In this iframe i have a form

```
<div id="main"></div>
<form id="fileForm" method="POST" action="https://othersub.samedomain.de/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="filename" type="file" id="filename"><br>
    <input name="action" type="hidden" value="fileupload">
    <a href="#" id="file-upload">upload</a>
</form>
```

In my JS i have this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#file-upload").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();     
    console.log("CLICK EVENT");
    $("#fileForm").submit();
});

$("#fileForm").ajaxForm({
    'target': '#main',
    'dataType':  'json',
    'type': 'POST',
    'url': 'https://othersub.samedomain.de/upload',
    beforeSubmit: function(){
        /* show loading */      
    },
    success: function(response, statusText, xhr, $form) {               
        /* do */
    },
    error: function(response, statusText, xhr, $form) {
        /* do */
    }
});

});
```

So i click on my upload button and i become a bad Error in IE:
(Access Denied) SCRIPT5

That is this line (554) of code:

```
submitFn.apply(form);
```

or more:

```
try {
form.submit();
} catch(err) {
// just in case form has element with name/id of 'submit'
var submitFn = document.createElement('form').submit;
submitFn.apply(form);
}
```

This happends in old IE when he has to use the iframe upload.
I hope u can help.

Best Regards

Comment: You can't programmatically invoke a file chooser dialog AND programmatically submit a form in IE.  IE does not allow this, and this is a well discussed case here on SO.

Comment: possible duplicate of [form submit - IE access denied - same domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667856/form-submit-ie-access-denied-same-domain)

Answer (score 0):

Has one big problem with input file, On IE is necessary the click over this element, if you use one javascript to simulate this click, you got one error after submit. Try this, put the input file with alpha 0 and filter 0 over a fake button to chose the file

sample

```
START HTML--------------------------------
 < form ... >
   < input type="file" id="ID_INPUTFILE" ....>
   < a href="#" id="FAKE_BUTTON"> CHOSE YOU FILE < /a>
   ...
 < /form >
< /html>
END HTML----------------------------------
```

START CSS---------------------------------
< style>
 form { position:relative; }
 #FAKE_BUTTON {
 width:  200px;
 height: 30px;
 left:   10px;
 top:    10px;
 z-index:2;
}
 #ID_INPUTFILE {
 position: absolute;
 width:    200px;  /*WIDTH_OF_FAKE_BUTTON*/
 height:   30px;   /*HEIGHT_OF_FAKE_BUTTON*/
 left:     10px;   /*LEFT_POSITION_OF_FAKE_BUTTON */
 top:      10px;   /*TOP_POSITION_OF_FAKE_BUTTON */
 z-index:  3;      /*ALWAY OVER FAKE BUTTON */
 opacity:  0.0;    /*TO PUT INVISIBLE */
 filter:   alpha(opacity=0); /*TO PUT INVISIBLE fix ie */
}
< /style>
END CSS-----------------------------------