# Jquery .submit() event to firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cross-browser

HTML

```
<form action="includes/photos.php" id="joinPhotoUploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
</form>
```

Jquery

```
$('div#photoCropContainer').click(function() {
  $('input#file').trigger('click');
});
```

And

```
$(document).on('change','input#file', function() {
    alert('ready to upload');
    $('form#joinPhotoUploadForm').submit();
});
```

When someone clicks the Div@photoCropContainer it trigers a click on the file input, shows the popup and sends the file. This works on FF & Chrome.

On IE9 however I always get the popup but no other reply...

Can anyone give me any advise?

thanks

Comment: I tried it, nothing works in FF. Provide some FIDDLE

Comment: Something trying to upload [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BayjF/)

Comment: Where is the `div#photoCropContainer` ? Is it a wrapper of the form?

Comment: Here it is, yes, I see problem [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BayjF/1/)

Comment: @Adam, There is pretty much questions on this issue (IE fires change event on `input[type=file]` only if it had not empty value). You can try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389341/jquery-change-event-to-input-file-on-ie

Comment: I checked out your jsfiddle and it **worked out** in _FF 15, Chrome (latest) and IE9_

Comment: interesting... it doesn't work for me in IE9... that is the jsfiddle page

Comment: Guys - in IE9 the fiddler doesn't fire for me... do others get the same response?

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in IE9 console "access denied" on form submit line, thats why nothing works. Look at this question [ie javascript form submit with file input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396411/ie-javascript-form-submit-with-file-input)