# JQuery .submit() Fails in IE9

Tags: jquery, html

Below is a Jsfiddle and a link to a question just recently asked.

If you go to the jsfiddle page in FF or Chrome and click the 'Click Me!' you can select a file and once you ok the file the page will look for a php script. In IE it doesn't look for the php script - just does nothing.

Do other people get the same result? Any ideas as to how to get IE9 to respond?

http://jsfiddle.net/BayjF/1/

[Jquery .submit() event to firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444648/jquery-submit-event-to-firing)

Comment: Duplicate of [Jquery .submit() event to firing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444648/jquery-submit-event-to-firing). Please refrain from posting the same question twice. You can update the original question with your fiddle instead.

Comment: sure... sorry - wasn't getting a reply

Comment: [this](https://paydirtapp.com/blog/we-dont-support-ie/) is my favorite solution to all internet explorer related problems. it is f***** unpopular. last time i posted it as an answer i got downvoted 12 times before it got deleted, and it is unworkable for most people, but it is a good reading, and at least makes you feel better, if you get really enraged by IE.

Comment: @Kuro, I can see why you get downvoted. This advocates giving up IE as a solution, and most of us cannot afford to do that.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi , yes, i understand that one can experience no small difficulties once he decides, that he does not support IE. still, one can gain something, at least in terms of self respect, by not supporting something that he sees as simply wrong. it is much easier to spend some extra time correcting many errors IE provides us with, than foolishly trying to headbutt the market, but then again, some of us are idealists ( and some of us are fools :) ), and every revolution starts with a few dedicated personas. maybe one day. just sayin :)

Comment: @kuro I'm with you. I posted something similar once with the same result. Downvotes, then deletion. But if all of us developers would just do what you did. Everyone would be forced to use a real browser or IE would be forced to fix their s**t. And for the record I have been making the step and removing IE support for some of my sites.

Comment: The reason you got downvoted not because it is wrong to give up on IE entirely (i'm all for that). The reason is that it probably completely dodged the initial question. How would the answer "don't use/support IE" be helpful when someone has an IE issue.