# jquery .trigger() on input file fails for IE9

Tags: jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JQuery .submit() Fails in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12445499/jquery-submit-fails-in-ie9)

http://jsfiddle.net/BayjF/8/

This piece of Jquery doesn't work in IE:

```
$('div#photoCropContainer').click(function() { 
    $('input#file').trigger('click'); 
});
```

In the JSFiddle on IE9 - if you click browse button, then submit fires automatically.

If however you click 'click me!' and choose a file the submit doesn't fire.

It appears the issue is with the .trigger() on IE9 - anyone have any ideas or advice?

thx

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is a security limitation in IE.

You should use a `<label>` around your *input* (or using `for="file"` attribute).
Clicking on the label will automatically trigger click event on your input, thus opening the file chooser.

Comment: This does not work for me, it opens the file choose but then I have the same problem as above; the submit does not work correctly. In IE9.