# Submitting a form on change event of file input in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, file-upload

Invoking a click event on file input element to show browser dialog, results in **access is denied** message in IE, when submitting the form. Is there no way to achieve file uploads by invoking click event on input file manually, in IE,  using pure javascript?

Comment: So is the issue submitting a form when the change event fires, or the fact that triggering a click on the upload button doesn't work ?

Comment: I can submit the form on change event, when I click on the browse button manually. But when I use .click() function, to invoke the browser dialog by clicking on some different button, I'm shown access denied message when the form is about to submit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ie javascript form submit with file input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396411/ie-javascript-form-submit-with-file-input)