# Submit form requires more than one click in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Please find below file code where multiple file upload functionality is given. On click of upload link it opens input file browser window where we select file and then click on submit.

In chrome, submit button submits the form on first click but In IE, it does not submit the form on first click.

In IE, If we select one file using upload link then submit button submits the form in second click.

If we select two file then it submits the form in 3rd click and accordingly.

Please let me know how to stop this event chain to submit in one click.

Please find below test.html file as,

https://www.dropbox.com/s/o7dwxhjnegxo0fo/Test.html?dl=0

Comment: Please edit the relevant HTML code into your question. That way, even if the Dropbox link stops working at some point, people will still be able to understand your question.

Comment: What is the purpose of your `submit` handler containing nothing but `stopPropagation()`? As per [the docs](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/), *"Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event."* ~ Since there are no "parent handlers" for your submit, the whole handler seems pointless and perhaps causing some weird IE bug. Also, as per [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), please edit your OP to include the relevant code; don't expect the reader to download files just to understand your question.

Comment: Every version of IE has its own set of bugs and issues.  Which IE version are you talking about?

Comment: Please us http://jsfiddle.net or http://codepen.io/ instead of uploading a file with DropBox. i wouldn't recommend people to download files like this from DropBox (you know, viruses and all that...)

Comment: @Mack Dsoza once you've posted your code per Pikamander2, Sparky and Yaron's advice, I would suggest looking [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22109414/2759272) for an answer similar to mine (which has been deleted), or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9396411/2759272) for just about every other possible solution. This question is most likely a duplicate.